# Oracle and rman recovery catalog

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I have been handed an oracle database (10.1.0.5.0) with no documentation and very little rman information and I need to change the existing the backup location drive for rman backups.
Before I do that I want to check if the database has a recovery catalog. How do I do this?
If no recovery catalog exists how to do I query existing script names and script content?

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you on?

The CATALOG option will be on the RMAN command line or in the recovery script file.  Just "grep" for catalog as a start.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your RMAN backup log file. Where you will see where you are connecting to catalog or not.

The output will look like as below

```
Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Thu May 2 08:03:55 2019
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

RMAN>
connected to recovery catalog database
recovery catalog schema release 12.02.00.01. is newer than RMAN release
```

2. Check your backup script where you will see where you are connected to RMAN Catalog or not

Please grep for "connect catalog"

```
$ cat script.sh | grep 'connect catalog'
```